# Angular - how to determine if my custom directive evaluates an expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, attributes, autofocus

I have this custom directive and I'd like the script the evalaute as an expression such as

`form-focus="coursesCtrl.coursesAndCourseRelatedExpenses.length"` instead of just `form-focus="true"`

I would like to use this custom attribute conditionally

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').directive('formFocus', function ($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            form: '=formFocus'
        },
        require: '^form',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            if (attr.formFocus) { 
                scope.$watch($parse(attr.formFocus), function(value) {
                    if (value === true) { 
                        $timeout(function() {
                            elem[0].focus(); 
                        });
                    }
                });
            }   
            scope.$on('formFocus', function (e, name) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    if (elem.find('input').length > 0) {
                        elem.find('input')[0].focus();
                    } else if (elem.find('a').length > 0) {
                        elem.find('a')[0].focus();
                    }
                }, (name === 'educationInfoForm' ? 1000 : 0));
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: You mean you want to require that the binding be `"form-focus="coursesCtrl.coursesAndCourseRelatedExpenses.length"` or something similar?. If so, rethink your design.